# Multiple backgrounds in Safari

Tags: css, background, safari, shorthand, cover

This code works for me in Chrome & FF but for some reason not in Safari. Safari should [support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds) though. Safari reports there's something wrong with the syntax. This is probably true but I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
.frontpage {
background: url(logo.png) no-repeat center center / 50% auto,
            url(background.png) no-repeat center center / cover;
}
```

I need the background.png to act as a cover and fill the whole background of the page while the logo should be centered and have a width of 50% & height auto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `background-size` appart, to avoid this kind of failure with browsrers that are not yet old but not up to date anymore :)

edit

```css
.frontpage {
background: url(logo.png) no-repeat center center,
            url(background.png) no-repeat center center;
background-size: 50% auto,
            cover;
}
```

Comment: How do I make the background-size: cover to affect only the background.png and not the logo.png while still having two backgrounds stacking on top of each other? If I just separate it and add it below both of the images start using the cover mode which ruins the logo stretching it like the background.

Comment: Great, that worked! Didn't know at all about the fact that you can use the comma separated list in each of the different background properties individually. Thanks!